# Can't store posted values to vector

Tags: c++, sockets, ncurses

I'm creating a client-server chat-like app in `C++` and I'm doing UI in `ncurses`.
I want to store all messages to `vector<char *> msgVector` to be able to redraw the whole screen regularly.
Nevertheless when I want to print the values out, all items have the same value - the last accepted message.

```
void acceptMessages() {
char buffer[256];    
fd = c->createClient2Fd("localhost", 12345);
while (true) {
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof ( buffer));
    int l = recv(fd, buffer, sizeof ( buffer), 0);
    msgVector.push_back(buffer);      
    redrawScreen();    
}

void redrawScreen() {    
    erase();
    mvhline(0, 0, ACS_HLINE, COLS);
    mvhline(LINES - 2, 0, ACS_HLINE, COLS);
    mvaddstr(LINES - 1, 0, "MESSAGE:");
    move(LINES - 1, 9);    

    // prints right count of messages
    // but on every line is printed only the last message
    for (int i = 0; i != msgVector.size(); i++)
        cout<<msgVector[i]<<endl;
    move(LINES - 1, 9);
    refresh();    
}
```

So lets say, that accepted messages were:

```
1) Hello world!
2) My name is John
3) John Doe
4) Test message
```

Then I get the output:

```
Test message
Test message
Test message
Test message
```

Could anybody explain me, what can cause this and how to fix it?

Comment: Consider using `vector<string>`

Comment: You are storing `char*` in your vector. These pointers point to the same buffer. The buffer gets overwritten on each iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pointer which `buffer` decays into is always the same (since it's the same variable), so you're always pushing the same pointer onto the vector. That will, after the loop has completed, point to `buffer` (obviously), which will contain the last message only.

To solve this, consider using `std::vector<std::string>` instead and pushing back `std::string(buffer)` during each iteration.

Comment: I've already tried this, nevertheless, then I couldn't use `mvaddstr`, because it can't work with `strings`.But thanks for the explanation of the source of this problem

Comment: @Dworza Then you obtain a C string from the `std::string` by calling `.c_str()` on it.

Comment: But if I've understood you well, `.c_str()` won't help me, because I've got right opposite problem - I want to create `char *` from `string` and not vice versa...

Comment: @Dworza **Google `c_str()`** and develop some common sense.

Comment: @Dworza Anything you can you can do with a string pointed to by `char*` you can do with `std::string`. Try `std::string buffer("hello"); char *ptr = &buffer[0];`

Comment: @H2CO3 I can feel your head shaking from here ;)

Comment: ah..you're right, guys.. Sorry for such a lame question... the plus points I get here at SO in java section, I loose in C++ section x-)

Comment: @Dworza It's not a lame question. You included what you were doing, what you expected to happen, what results you got, and the code responsible for the problem. The only problem I can see is that you were resistant to the solution provide without following up a bit more yourself. Hopefully you won't be so resistant in the future ;)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Exactly, I was going to write the same but was too lazy... this question is not bad, rather the expectations are too high (if I give some directions towards the solution, I expect some more effort to be made).

Answer (score 1):

As [H2CO3 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16885814/845568) every element in the vector points to the same block of memory. Even worse `buffer` is a local variable that is destroyed once you return from `acceptMessages`. This results in undefined behavior and text you output to the screen can be *anything*, not just the last line of text you added.

You should switch to using `std::vector<std::string>` so that a copy of `buffer` is made and the memory is properly managed for you.